# Why would sshd reject a key when options are given?

Tags: sshd

sshd accepts connections from my public key, however, when I add the following options to the start of `authorized_keys`:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty [SSH KEY HERE]
```

it gives me

```
[user]@[host]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

when I try to connect.

What are the possible reasons for this? This is not a problem that I've been able to figure out by searching, and currently the solution I've been going with is to simply leave those options out -- however in the interest of security, I'd like to start using them. I do not see any specific errors when running with `-vvvv`, although there is a lot to parse, so I may have missed something.

sshd is running on a different (<1000) port, and the user has been added to `AllowUsers`, and there are not many non-standard settings (no challenge-response allowed, PAM allowed, etc.)

Comment: just curious, can you test again without `no-pty` option?

Comment: One of the first things I tried, unfortunately that gives the same error ://

Comment: Add one or more `-v` options to your `ssh` command. Read `man ssh`.

Comment: @waltinator That is exactly what I did several times in the last day. Regardless, at 4am just now, it just started working. I'm honestly not sure what the difference was, since I have scoured the piece of text I've been pasting for any differences and it does not seem considerably different ¯\_ (ツ)_/¯ Definitely a WTF moment because as far as I am aware no configuration has changed.